# Is Unhooking event handlers needed to avoid memory leaks in IE

Tags: javascript, dom

I am having some memory leak problems in IE.

I have been reading, that not unhooking event handlers in IE, could cause memory leaks. Is this true?
Could my memory leaks be cause by not detaching event handlers when the user leaves a page?

Comment: When you tried unhooking the handlers, did it fix the leak?

Comment: this is a big piece of code, it would take me some time to go through all events and try that. I'm not the original author

Comment: It is possible for memory leaks if a handler closes over a variable scope that contains the same element that received the handler.

Comment: Which version(s) of IE are affected in your tests? Are you sure there is a memory leak *when* the user leaves a page? Because, when a page's `window` context is destroyed, *all* JavaScript resources it used *should* be reclaimed/released, the *earlier* IE memory leaks related to things like replacing things with `innerHTML` which did not correctly release events .. but once the entire `window` context is destroyed: problem solved with a new blank-slate.

Comment: It happens in all IE version including IE9. When I refresh the page the memory usage of IE keeps jumping up by around 100mb!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Douglas Crockford has an [excellent post on JSscript memory leaks](http://javascript.crockford.com/memory/leak.html) (JScript is IE's implementation of JavaScript/ECMAScript).

It basically comes down to this: IE has separate memory management (and thus garbage collection) for the DOM and for JScript. Because of this, IE has trouble cleaning up the cycling references between DOM objects and event handlers.

The way to work around this is to make sure that you always remove the event handlers from the DOM objects (or set them to `null`) before you throw away the DOM object.

Comment: Does this happen in IE9 also?

Answer (score 0):

Some of the older browsers have had issues in regards to this. When there's registered event handler, consider this;

1) in script engine a callback registry is kept, an event is bound here with 2 things, a DOMNode and a function pointer

2) DOMNode may 'dissapear' - and same thing could 'happen' to the function (less likely though).

code like `<a onclick="a = (a?a+1:0);" id="getme">...` results in an anonumous function which you will reference by `var anchor = document.getElementById('getme'); anchor.onclick`' To perfectly purge it one must `delete anchor.onclick` in addition to detach eventlistener.

Some people may wrant at this code but it will certainly wipe the anchors onclick away

```
var a=document.getElementById('getme')
window.detachEvent("onclick", a.onclick);
delete a.onclick;
a.parentNode.removeChild(a)
```