# Memory Build Up In IE9

Tags: javascript, html, dom, internet-explorer-9

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Is Unhooking event handlers needed to avoid memory leaks in IE](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11461569/is-unhooking-event-handlers-needed-to-avoid-memory-leaks-in-ie)

I'm having some trouble pin pointing the source of a memory build up in IE9. The memory usage jumps up by about 50Mb each page refresh. For example look at Nordstrom.com, each page refresh the memory jumps up quite a bit and it gets to a point where after 30 pages or more the page becomes unresponsive. I don't have any IE add-ons installed. I know IE has some issue garbage collecting JavaScript and DOM with closures and circular references, but I thought that has been fixed for the most part in IE9. Any ideas? What could cause a memory build up in IE9?

Comment: I have to admit to getting some jumps on each refresh on the Nordstrom page, but it's not even close to 50Mb per jump.  Puzzling.

Answer (score 0):

Probably you've run into that 'useful feature' where IE caches all eventhandlers that where ever set until the window is closed.
This is to my knowledge the most noticeable and documented memory-leak IE(9 still) has.
Check-out [this SO post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11461569/is-unhooking-event-handlers-needed-to-avoid-memory-leaks-in-ie) for more info.